# Adding text to inside of parenthesis deletes everything after closing parenthesis

Tags: zsh, iterm2, prezto

When using `zsh` to write a `for` loop, if I attempt to add text inside parenthesis (command substitution) after I've finished writing the loop, `zsh` deletes everything after the last parenthesis. A bit hard to explain, so I've created a [screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4xJZ.jpg) to visualize the issue a bit better.

`.zpreztorc`, `.zshrc`, `.zprofile`, `.profile`, `.zprezto/*`, etc. have not been modified from default.

I'm unable to replicate the issue using GNU bash v3.2.57 in the same profile on iTerm2.

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0)
```

Running iTerm2 v3.3.0 with shell integration and the [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) framework for `zsh`.

I would like to be able to add pipe commands to the end of my command substitution without having to retype the rest of my loop every time.

Comment: Can not reproduce with my zsh (5.5.1). What happens if you do not use Prezto?